# How to draw a graph from CSV with TeX?

Tags: pgfplots, csv

I am a complete beginner with TeX, I would like to draw JMH benchmark graph using TeX. Since I have output results in CSV format.
This is my actual code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\title{Performance Report}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=Getbytes performance,
xlabel = String length,
ylabel = Performance op/s,
 ]

\addplot[
only marks,
mark = *,
      /pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
    x dir = both,
    y dir = both,
    x explicit,
    y explicit,
   ]
table [
x=Param: length,
y=Score,
 ]
{jmh-result-getbytes.csv};

\addlegendentry{Average value}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My CSV file:

```
"Benchmark","Mode","Threads","Samples","Score","Score Error (99.9%)","Unit","Param: encoding","Param: length"
"test","thrpt",1,25.000000,24275.400025,695.792149,"ops/ms",ISO-8859-1,1
"test","thrpt",1,25.000000,23954.805784,545.186364,"ops/ms",ISO-8859-1,2
"test","thrpt",1,25.000000,23205.982297,573.971327,"ops/ms",ISO-8859-1,4
"test","thrpt",1,25.000000,24272.662601,937.668790,"ops/ms",ISO-8859-1,8
"test","thrpt",1,25.000000,24324.370910,1122.289177,"ops/ms",ISO-8859-1,16
"test","thrpt",1,25.000000,23960.521519,928.378626,"ops/ms",ISO-8859-1,32
```

For me the x is : `Param: length` 
and y is : `score`

But when I run `make plot.pdf` I get the following message error :

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'Param:     length' from
 table '\\pgfplotstableread@filename@@table@name '. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases)..
```

Comment: I have added this line \pgfplotstableread[col header=false] I still get an error, I am not sure what the problem used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The percent character in the column header `"Score Error (99.9%)"` makes trouble because it removes the rest of the line as comment. The following example works around it by ignoring this character.

Also the header entries are surrounded by quotes. Quoting seems unsupported by `pgfplots`. Therefore the example adds the quotes to the column title specification as part of the title. Also you have to pray, that the cells do not contain the comma. Otherwise `pgfplots` thinks a new column has started, even if the comma is inside quotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\title{Performance Report}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=Getbytes performance,
    xlabel = Performance op/s,
    ylabel = String length,
 ]

\addplot[
    only marks,
    mark = *,
    /pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
    x dir = both,
    y dir = both,
    x explicit,
    y explicit,
   ]
table [
    header=true,
    col sep=comma,
    ignore chars=\%,
    x="Param: length",
    y="Score",
 ]
{jmh-result-getbytes.csv};

\addlegendentry{Average value}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Serious question: why do you have that red tint on the background? :)

Comment: @henry To make clear, that this is an image, apart from the background, there are thin double lines above and below. The markup language here is quite limited, thus I am using the "blockquote" feature with `>` at the start of line.

Comment: Oh... I see. Interesting. :)